# There is a directory which never gets copied and not tracked

Tags: git

How come a fork in local if given

```
$ git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

while there is `build` directory in the clone root/top which never gets copied wholly into remote and it's not in :

```
$ cat  .gitignore 
*~
*.o
*.tar.gz
```

Please help figure out what the logical thing is going on

Comment: Try `git check-ignore -v ./build` in repo root to see if maybe some other configuration excludes it. `git check-ignore --help` for details.

Comment: Is the directory empty (or contains ignored files only)? If not, have you modified your local ignore-file, `.git/info/exclude`?